# SSIS export database

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How to convert all database in particular database server into solution file

We tried but this is getting converted to sql file but need it in sln file

Comment: You can use visual studio to create a sql databse project. I guess you are on sql serVer

Comment: are you going to convert the data from some databases into one? or are you going to transfer and sync structure and database design? are your databases on different servers?

Comment: Database on same server